# Multiple Rest API Calls In PowerShell

Tags: powershell, rest, powerbi

I am posting multiple Rest Api calls (About 1500) to the Power BI server using the below code.
I have a collection of about 1500 Workspaces id($wid) that I am posting using a for-each loop
But after about 200 requests, I get an exception with error 429 (Too Many Requests).

I have tried adding a sleep (2 minutes) after every 100 requests but I still get the same error after 200 requests. And I end up in the catch block of the below code. The code waits until the Retry-time is reached (about 45 minutes) before processing further requests. And the same process repeats.

```
foreach ($wid in $IdCollection )
{
$webURI = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups/$wid/users"
try {
$response = Invoke-RestMethod $webURI -Method 'GET'  -Headers $headers
$ExportResults += $response.value #store the response }
catch {
IF ($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode -eq 429) {
    [int] $delay = $_.Exception.Response.Headers[“Retry-After”]
    Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount
    GenerateAccessToken # New access token
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod $webURI -Method 'GET'-Headers $headers # Post request again    
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: This is almost certainly some rate-limiting setting on the server side and nothing to do with PowerShell or your script.  Check the documentation to see if there is anything you can change on your account to increase the limit.

Comment: It looks like there might be a separate endpoint for admins to query multiple workspaces in a single ```GetGroupsAsAdmin```call - see https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/avoiding-workspace-loops-by-expanding-navigation-properties-in-the-getgroupsasadmin-api/. Not sure if that will give you the exact info you're after though...